# Wrong "Duplicate entry '284093' for key 'PRIMARY'" message

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Preamble: This question may be useful to people who get `wrong` error messages when using MySQL. Proof is given that the error message is wrong.

In a MySQL database (version 5.7.18), MyISAM table "sensorhistory" has a column "id" of type "int(11)" with Extra "auto_increment". Data are inserted from an application written in C#. The `INSERT` query does NOT write the `id` column directly, of course. That's what the "auto_increment" is for. The table contains further 30 fields of float and varchar types, resp., plus a `DateTime(3)`. The parameterized query is long.

I receive following error message:

`Duplicate entry '284093' for key 'PRIMARY'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at DataStorage.SensorHistoryDatastore.StoreSensorHistory(IReadOnlyList'1 _reports, Boolean _canRetry) in C:\Users\bernhard.hiller\SVN\Product-SW\trunk\C_DataStorage\PhysicalContainers\SensorHistoryDatastore.cs:line 84`

Oddly, when I execute `SELECT max(id) FROM sensorhistory` in MySQL Workbench, I get a maximum value of `284092`, i.e. 1 less than the "duplicate entry". That is proof that the error message is wrong.

I'd like to know how such an odd error can occur, and how to fix it.

Addendum:

An "Analyze table" in MySQL Workbench showed that the table is corrupt:
`Found key at page 6585344 that points to record outside datafile` 
It could be repaired with a simple `Repair table sensorhistory`
I am still interested in how that corruption of the table can have occured.

By the way: a big THANK YOU to all those DOWNVOTERS who seem to be unable to read the text: this is not a f***ing stupid question about a "duplicate key", because I showed proof that the duplicate value does not exist at all!

Addendum 208-09-12:

The error re-occured after just 1 day, same table, same error message (just with a new value).

Comment: Could you show the INSERT query itself?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Eventlog showed more than 7 crashes between Sep 7 and Sep 11 (id 6008: "The previous system shutdown was unexpected"). The newest entry in the table sensorhistory was shortly before such crash in both cases.

The crashes ended on Sep 11 in the morning. I do not know the reason - other people are working on that test machine too. There were no more database issues then.

I conclude that a sudden Windows crash caused some inconsistency in the database, which then lead to that error message.